# Iterating through lists in python

Tags: python, list

I am making a program that takes in user input in the form of test answers at first. It then asks for an answer key. Finally, it should compare each item in the list and determine a grade.

Here is an example run of my program in which hopefully it would work:

```
How many questions are there? >> 5
What is your answer for question #1 >> a
What is your answer for question #2 >> a
What is your answer for question #3 >> a
What is your answer for question #4 >> a
What is your answer for question #5 >> a


What is the correct answer for question #1 >> a
What is the correct answer for question #2 >> a
What is the correct answer for question #3 >> a
What is the correct answer for question #4 >> a
What is the correct answer for question #5 >> d

Total number correct : 4
Total number possible: 5
Grade = 4.0/5.0, 0.8%
```

Here is what actually happens:

```
How many questions are there? >> 5

What is your answer for question #1 >> a

What is your answer for question #2 >> a

What is your answer for question #3 >> a

What is your answer for question #4 >> a

What is your answer for question #5 >> a

Responses:

1. a
2. a
3. a
4. a
5. a

What is the correct answer for question #1 >> c

What is the correct answer for question #2 >> a

What is the correct answer for question #3 >> a

What is the correct answer for question #4 >> a

What is the correct answer for question #5 >> a

Responses:

1. c
2. a
3. a
4. a
5. a
a = c ?
a = a ?
a = a ?
a = a ?
a = a ?
a = c ?
a = a ?
a = a ?
a = a ?
a = a ?
a = c ?
a = a ?
a = a ?
a = a ?
a = a ?
a = c ?
a = a ?
a = a ?
a = a ?
a = a ?
a = c ?
a = a ?
a = a ?
a = a ?
a = a ?
20
Number of correct answers = 20 out of 5
Your score is: -3.0
```

I am unsure as to why this is happening, is it perhaps the way I iterate through both lists in grading? Here is my code:

```
class Grader:
    def grade(self):
        # get number of questions
        numOfQuestions = input("How many questions are there? >> ")

        # start gathering answers
        i = 1
        responses = []
        while i <= int(numOfQuestions):
            entry = input("\nWhat is your answer for question #" + str(i) + " >> ")
            responses += entry
            i += 1

        # display user responses
        print("\nResponses:\n")
        j = 1
        for r in responses:
            print(str(j) + ". " + r)
            j+=1

        # grade the responses
        # input answer key
        x = 1
        answers = []
        while x <= int(numOfQuestions):
            aentry = input("\nWhat is the correct answer for question #" + str(x) + " >> ")
            answers += aentry
            x += 1

        # display answer key
        print("\nResponses:\n")
        y = 1
        for z in answers:
            print(str(y) + ". " + z)
            y+=1

        # time to actually grade the exam
        numCorrect = 0
        for p in responses:
            for q in answers:
                print(p+" = " +q+" ?")
                if p == q:
                    numCorrect += 1

        # issue a grade
        print(str(numCorrect))
        print("Number of correct answers = " + str(numCorrect) + " out of " + str(numOfQuestions))
        grade = int(numOfQuestions) - int(numCorrect)
        grade = grade / int(numOfQuestions)
        print("Your score is: " + str(grade))





if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Grader()
    a.grade()
```

Comment: The while loops confused me. I wrote it out so that it works for you as intended. It wasn't working for a number of different reasons. Primarily because of the last two while loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's here:

```
numCorrect = 0
for p in responses:
    for q in answers:
        print(p+" = " +q+" ?")
        if p == q:
            numCorrect += 1
```

That's comparing *every* response to *every* answer. You want to compare each response only to its corresponding answer. The easiest way is with the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip) function, like:

```
numCorrect = 0
for p, q in zip(responses, answers):
    print(p+" = " +q+" ?")
    if p == q:
        numCorrect += 1
```

Comment: You're welcome! Note that there are other ways to do this. For example, your `i` variable tracks the number of answers that have been, so you could have written `for num in range(i): if responses[num] == answers[num]: ...`. You could also use another data structure to store your responses and answers together. My answer was just the bare minimum required to get your current code up and running.

Answer (score 1):

for comparison you can use zip method with which we can loop two list same time here is a small change for answers comparison for question loop

```
for p,q in zip(responses,answers):
    print(p+" = " +q+" ?")
    if p == q:
        numCorrect += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Grader:
    def grade(self):
        # get number of questions
        numOfQuestions = input("How many questions are there? >> ")

        # start gathering answers
        i = 1
        responses = []
        for i in range(0,int(numOfQuestions)):
            entry = input("\nWhat is your answer for question #" + str(i+1) + " >> ")
            responses.append(entry)


        # display user responses
        print("\nResponses:\n")

        for i in range(0,len(responses)):
            print(str(i) + ". " + responses[i])


        # grade the responses
        # input answer key
        answers = []
        for i in range (0,len(responses)):
            aentry = input("\nWhat is the correct answer for question #" + str(i+1) + " >> ")
            answers.append(aentry)


        # display answer key
        print("\nResponses:\n")

        for i in range(0, len(answers)):
            print(str(i) + ". " + answers[i])


        # time to actually grade the exam
        numCorrect = 0
        for i in range(0, len(answers)):
            print(str(i)," = ",answers[i]," ?")
            if responses[i] == answers[i]:
                numCorrect += 1

        # issue a grade
        print(str(numCorrect))
        print("Number of correct answers = " + str(numCorrect) + " out of " + str(numOfQuestions))
        grade = int(numOfQuestions) - int(numCorrect)
        if grade==int(0.0):
             print("Scored 100%")
        else:
             grade = int(numCorrect)/int(numOfQuestions)
             print("Your score is: ",grade)





if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Grader()
    a.grade()
```